# React material-table - set row height

Tags: reactjs, material-table

First of all, I have tested all possible solutions I have founded and I still didn't solve my problem.

I want to put a shorter height in my material-table rows. This is what it looks like right now.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDzYD.png)

I would like my rows to have a height similar to the headers in that image. I have tried many things, one of them was the following:

```
    options={{
         headerStyle: {
             whiteSpace: "nowrap",
             height: 20,
             maxHeight: 20,
             padding: 0
         },
         rowStyle: {
             height: 20,
             maxHeight: 20,
             padding: 0
         },
    }}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me.

Answer (score 7):

You can set options in material-table

```
options={{
  padding: "dense",
}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Added the above code as a property to <MaterialTable> worked for me. material-table v 2.0.3

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `withStyles` and update the specific element class style, so it will reflect to all the elements. Check the working example as you expected here : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rs70x?file=/demo.js:192-248)

```js
import MuiTableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';

const TableCell = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    height: 10,
    padding:0
  }
}))(MuiTableCell);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with React Material-Table. I fixed adding this in the global index.css  of the project:

```
.MuiTableCell-root  {
  padding: 0 14px !important;
}
```

and then i could modify the height in the rowStyle in the options of the Material-Table component:

```
options = {
    rowStyle: {
        height: "20px"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much more simplified, overwrite padding of 16px to smaller size...<TableCell style={{padding:5px}} ...>.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by including  padding: "dense", property to options

options={{
padding: "dense",
}}

[image: My solution]

Answer (score -1):

I think the link below might be helpful for you.

[customizing material ui table](https://medium.com/dev-genius/material-ui-customize-tables-a9f744b0ed9c)